# Tinnitus caused due to random impulses?

Tags: hearing, tinnitus

Usually when I experience a sudden loud noise or silence I hear this sound..
Okay a website says this

> A common cause of tinnitus is inner ear cell damage. Tiny, delicate hairs in your inner ear move in relation to the pressure of sound waves. This triggers ear cells to release an electrical signal through a nerve from your ear (auditory nerve) to your brain. Your brain interprets these signals as sound. If the hairs inside your inner ear are bent or broken, they can "leak" random electrical impulses to your brain, causing tinnitus

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/1ixn1n/eli5_what_is_the_ringing_noise_we_hear_when)
So my doubt is why do we experience short term tinnitus,like for a minute or so,what happens to the broken inner hair